# Bootstrap, align four pics in a row without gaps

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

]I would like to get the structure of this site with bootstrap. How do I proceed? When I use no padding row with margins and padding set to 0 the content is just aligned left. With the deafult col class I get white space between the boxes I would use for the containers of the images.

The image is below cause I need 10 reputation to post images.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71295596/grid.jpg

Comment: Post your code too. We can't repair your toaster if you only send us a picture :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imo people these days are getting too boostrap dependient.

Insteed of changing bootstrap to adapt to what you want, messing with the css and overwritten properties I find it MUCH easier to make your own css when (in this case) you just need a few lines.

with this basic html structure:

```
<div>
    <img src="your image" alt=""/>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="your image" alt=""/>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="your image" alt=""/>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="your image" alt=""/>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="your image" alt=""/>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="your image" alt=""/>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="your image" alt=""/>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="your image" alt=""/>
</div>
```

and just these CSS:

```
div {
    width:25%;
    float:left; 
}
div img {
    width:100%; 
    display:block;
}
```

you have the layout you are looking for. Even more, you can add:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
div {width:50%;}
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
div {width:100%;}
}
```

and now it is totally responsive: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/1z00tvor/)**

Comment: well, you just gave us a pic.. this code looks exactly like your pic, so at the very least you may update the image showing exactly what you want. don't you think?

Comment: Yeap that was it. Many thanks :) PS: In the previous comment I had something wrong with my files.

Comment: np. glad I could help